# Eclipse plugin development - How to get the list of sub folders and keep navigating the folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing a file search module in Eclipse plugin development.
Now, I know the name of the path using IJavaProject.getOutputLocation(),
and I want to get all folders and files under the IPath directory.

I can see the APIs that create or get IFolder from the folder name but
I cannot find the thing that can return the list of the folders under a specific directory.

Could you please let me know how to et the list of sub folders from IPath?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IFolder` is an `IContainer`, so you can get a list of all sub-elements by calling `members()`. It will return an `IResource[]`. Test the actual type of each element via `instanceof` - it should be either `IFolder` or `IFile`.

An `IPath` is just a list of string segments, separated by '/'. Usually it is used to point to a file within the workspace, but this is not mandatory.

The method `IJavaProject#getOutputLocation()` returns a (workspace-relative) absolute path to the output folder of your java project (that's usually the `bin` directory where all the compiled stuff and other generated resources are stored).

```
IPath outputPath = project.getOutputLocation();
```

If you have a path that is workspace relative, you can get the actual `IFile` or `IFolder` by asking an `IContainer` - for example the `IWorkspaceRoot` (which is the root container of the workspace):

```
IFolder outputFolder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFolder(outputPath);
```

Now you could traverse the folder structure:

```
void printStructure(IContainer container, String intent) {
    for(IResource member : folder.members()) {
        System.out.println(intent + member.getName());
        if (member instanceof IContainer) {
            printStructure((IContainer)member, intent + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot see getMembers() method on IFolder or IContainer class.. Could you explain more in detail? Thanks.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, I got an idea now and your code works perfect. This is what I wanted to know and get. Thanks again!! :)